# Unable to use NPM package in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I installed both the `meteor-npm` package and the `crypto` npm package. After starting Meteor, the console outputs

```
npm: updating npm dependencies -- crypto
```

However when I tried using the npm package within the server:

```
var Crypto = Npm.require('crypto')
```

I get the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'
```

Next I tried

```
var Crypto = Meteor.require('crypto')
```

and I get the error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/athenawisdoms/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm/npm/main/node_modules/crypto'
```

I noticed the npm package is present at `/packages/npm/.npm/package/node_modules/crypto` and at `/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/node_modules/npm/node_modules/crypto` but not at `/Users/athenawisdoms/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm/npm/main/node_modules/` as mentioned in the error message.

Did the installation go wrong?

Comment: what happens when you open node and do `var x = require('crypto')`? Does that work?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I get `undefined` when doing that in node's REPL.

Comment: the response will always be undefined, but the question is whether `x` will be defined after. If you don't get an error, then it seems that it worked and that your package installation worked just fine. So your issue seems to have to do with meteor, not the npm package itself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the way Meteor interacts with NPM, and so I've created a [replication of the problem](https://github.com/mizzao/npm-crypto-bug) and [filed an issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1811). However, I soon realized that it was a red herring, as the package I was using actually wanted to use Node's `crypto` module and not the NPM one. Are you sure that this is not the case with your package as well?

I have a feeling this may be related to the fact that the doubly named `crypto` modules are probably trampling on each other.

Comment: Yes it was indeed using Node's `crypto` module~